# Include customized feature extraction methods in sklearn Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

In sklearn, it is possible to define a pipeline in the following way:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
estimators = [('reduce_dim', PCA()), ('clf', SVC())]
pipe = Pipeline(estimators)
```

Is it also possible to include custom feature extraction methods like

```
extract_features(image, cspace='RGB', 
                        pix_per_cell=128, cell_per_block=32, 
                        hog_channel=10)
```

and how would I do that?

Comment: Give some more info. What is `image`, a numpy matrix or a file path?

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py) where they have implemented custom methods into classes which can be used in `Pipeline`. Try this and post here if you got any more issues.